Tracing back the yaml file from helm release chart
The question sounds a bit weird so I'll add some context first.
We have several namespaces and helm releases scattered accross a kubernetes cluster, too much chaotically named to be identified through their names only (the whole cluster is an absolute mess and wasn't made by me, even worse it was hand-deployed).
I'm working on a script that updates a helm chart after modifying a values.yaml file. The problem I'm coming accross is that there are a LOT of yaml files with each one having their own helm release.
I have no idea how to pinpoint which release corresponds to the yaml file was edited, and I need the release name for the program to actually perform the update.
Hence my question, do helm releases, outside of the option "get values" which I can't use, have some kind of clue on which file has been used by which release ?

There are some standard Kubernetes labels that can identify what chart and release an object came from, but the chart does need to include them.  The boilerplate Helm gives you by default includes it but any given chart isn't necessarily guaranteed to include those or actually call them correctly.  A given YAML file isn't strongly connected to any particular Helm object.
